# select all first occurrances of p after h

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to select the first occurrance of `<p>` after each `<h1>` and `<h2>` when all these tags are sibligs (i.e. all belong to the same div). Paragraph does not necessarily follow the header immediately; there could be some images, or tables, or other elements in between.
The aim is to then style the first letter of such paragraphs. I do not want to use javascript or jQuery. Is this possible with css selectors only?

For example I would have something like:

```
<div>
<h1>Bla</h1>
<p class="Testo">BlaBla.</p> <!-- #1 -->
<p class="Testo">BlaBla.</p> <!-- #2 -->
<h2>BlaBlaBla</h2>
<p class="Testo">BlaBla.</p> <!-- #3 -->
<h2>BlaBlaBla</h2>
<div>
    <img>
    <p></p>                  <!-- #4 -->
</div>
<p class="Testo">BlaBla.</p> <!-- #5 -->
</div>
```

And I would like to select #1, #3 and #5. I am lost by now and appreciate some help.

If I use: `h1 + p.Testo:first-letter` and `h2 + p.Testo:first-letter` it does not select **#5** because it is not following the header immediately.

If I use: `h1 ~ p.Testo:first-letter` and `h2 ~ p.Testo:first-letter` it selects also **#2** because that is also a sibling of `h1`.

If I use `h1 > p.Testo:first-letter` and `h2 > p.Testo:first-letter` it selects **none** of them because they are siblings and not children; same for descendant selector `h1 p.Testo:first-letter` and `h2 p.Testo:first-letter`

If I use: `h1 ~ p.Testo:first-of-type:first-letter` and `h2 ~ p.Testo:first-of-type:first-letter` it selects only **#1**...

Comment: I don't think it's possible with CSS only without restructuring the HTML.

Comment: How would you restructure the HTML? I am open to hear suggestions and tips.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "first occurrence of X after H" selector does not exist.

The closest pure-CSS solution is (add `class="h"` to each of your `<h1>`, `<h2>` elements, or repeat the selectors for `h1`, `h2`, ..):

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dC4sB/1/

```
.h + p.Testo,
.h + *:not(p.Testo) + p.Testo,
.h + *:not(p.Testo) + *:not(p.Testo) + p.Testo,
.h + *:not(p.Testo) + *:not(p.Testo) + *:not(p.Testo) + p.Testo {
   /* repeat + *:not(p.Testo) for each additional sibling */
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: That is what I feared and did not want to hear :(
If I need an extra class, then I think I wuold rather define it for the `<p>` that I want to change and assign it selectively...
But thanks for the help and time spent!

Comment: @rodedo That is the best choice. My solution would be the only suitable solution if you were not allowed to change the HTML.

Answer (score 14):

I am a little late, but for future people looking forward to resolve this, you can actually use css3 pseudo selector *::first-of-type* [(read more here)](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_first-of-type.asp)
like this

```
p:first-of-type {
    color: #f00;
}
```

if you want it to be the first within one particular `div` you can use

```
div#id_div > p:first-of-type {
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

and that should do the trick! hope this help anyone still looking for this answer

Comment: Thanks. This really needs more prominence.

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is answered, but using [sass](http://sass-lang.com/) could be really cool as well

```
h1, h2, h3, h4
{
    & + p
    {
        color:red;
    }
}
```

Where & represent the parent element, once compiled it will turn it into

```
h1 + p { color:red }
h2 + p { color:red }
h3 + p { color:red }
h4 + p { color:red }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `h + p.Testo:first-letter`

Please check out [this link](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/selectors_adjacent.htm) I used to find my answer to this situation.

**Edit** (After careful re-read)

I see now you have attempted that, but you wanted to grab the 5th `p` which would have been selected by either entering a blank `<h>` before your requested 5th paragraph or...

```css
h + p.Testo:first-letter, div + p.Testo:first-letter
{
  css code here
}
```

Sorry, I didn't realize your html layout wasn't following your question...

Comment: Read the question carefully: `If I use: h1 + p.Testo:first-letter and h2 + p.Testo:first-letter it does not select #5 because it is not following the header immediately.`

Comment: Yeah I read it again haha, my bad read my edit... Sorry again